# Simple threading kills the kernel or does not behaves as expected

Tags: python

Sorry for the generic title, but really didn't know how to ask this question in any other way.

I'm trying to build a class that calls the builtin "input" function, but returns a default value if the user does not interact within a given timeout.

```
from threading import Thread

class timeout_input:

    def __init__(self, query, time, default=None):

        self._input = None
        self.query = query

        get_input_thread = Thread(target=self._get_input, daemon=True)

        get_input_thread.start()
        get_input_thread.join(timeout=time)

        if get_input_thread.is_alive():
            self.result = default
        else:
            self.result = self._input


    def _get_input(self):
        self._input = input(self.query)
        return

print(timeout_input("Input: ",3, 'default').result)
```

The problem is that when I run the code below and I enter an input (e.g. "1"), sometimes the function prints "1", other times prints "default" (and it shouldn't) and sometimes ever kills the kernel so that I receive a "Kernel died, restating" warning in the Spyder console.

is this something that has to do with the threading module?

Below is an example. I did't change *anything* in timeout_input.py during this test
[image: Example]

As you can see, Inputs [2] and [3] behaved as expected. Inputs [4] returned "default" also if an input was given and, immediately after, the kernel died.

Then, after restarting, In[ 1] behaved as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "kills the kernel"?

Answer (score 1):

[Original Answer](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3444#issuecomment-255624306)

This happens when your computer is slow to create a kernel (because it lacks enough RAM or it's undergoing high CPU usage, as @mrclary said before). To solve the problem, increase time to check if kernel is up. (ex. 6 seconds)

I suspected this because the code runs correctly as you specified on my machine

Comment: Weirdly, I have 32 GB of RAM mostly unused at the moment and my CPU is below 5% usage.

Answer (score 1):

I've run it 20 times and not found any error of this kind.
I ran it on python shell:

```
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: 2
2
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: 3
3
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: 4
4 
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: default
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: 1
1
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ python3 test.py
Input: 1
1
```

and numerous other examples,(also ran with words as input and got the output) nothing of that sort seems to happen in my case.It might be a problem with Spyder notebook.